# ping reports not receiving any package while tcpdump logs echo replies

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ping, tunnel

**INTRO:**

There's an `IPIP` tunnel (call it `megatun0`) to a machine connected to a private network. The `megatun0` tunnel is bound with the address `192.168.15.1`. One of the network interface on the machine remote machine has address `10.10.10.10`.

**PROBLEM:**

`ping -I megatun0 10.10.10.10` reports no `ICMP` echo replies received. Running `strace ping -I megatun0 10.10.10.10` didn't show up anything interesting except that

```
recvmsg(3, {msg_namelen=128}, 0)        = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

But when running `tcpdump icmp -nn -v` I got the following output:

```
22:29:32.220191 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 34344, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.15.1 > 10.10.10.10: ICMP echo request, id 25118, seq 6, length 64
22:29:32.388927 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 7361, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.10.10.10 > 192.168.15.1: ICMP echo reply, id 25118, seq 6, length 64
```

So in fact I got the echo replies from the host, but they were not reported by ping though.

Why might that happen?

Comment: Probably a missing route. With your network setup (`ip -br link; ip -4 -br addr; ip -4 route; ip -4 rule`), this should be be easier to figure out.